# Is there a way to show all apps deployed to your Meteor developer account?

Tags: meteor

I just signed up for a Meteor developer account and deployed my first app. I have searched and seen the blog post on the develop account but I have not found any information on how to login and view a list of all apps deployed to your account.

So for example after

```
meteor login
```

you could type

```
meteor list
```

and it would list all the apps deployed to this account

but I have not found any such command and I am wondering if it exists?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update**

The command has since been added use:

```
meteor list-sites
```

Make sure you're logged in first. Use `meteor login` to login, if you're not already.

---

At the moment this feature is not yet available. It should be available soon, according to the discussions on meteor-talk, with an API call and a meteor command like 'list'.

The apps listed on your [Meteor Developer account](https://www.meteor.com/account-settings) are **not** the same as your deployed apps. The apps listed there are the ones that have access to your meteor developer account via OAuth.

More Info:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/QPlmTfYf5gM
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/xFmGbAsmIck

Comment: Is there a web link to show all commands available to your meteor developer account?

Answer (score 0):

You can view your Developer Account Apps from the [Meteor Account settings](https://www.meteor.com/account-settings) page

Once you log in, you will see all of your apps listed under "Your Developer Account Apps"

Comment: All the apps deployed to your Meteor account do not show up here. You only manually add apps here to given other access to them I think.

Answer (score -1):

The command has been added. Use

```
meteor list-sites
```

To show all apps deployed to your account.